# Controller function call from JS- JSON parse error - only in firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework2

I have a button, which on click should insert the users into table.

Basically im stuck in calling the controller function from my javascript.

**HTML button.**

```
<div class="continue_btton">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="SaveSettings" value="<?php echo $this->translate('Update'); ?>" class="update bdr_rds2" onclick="if($('input[name=target_criteria]:checked').val() == 'optedin_users')
                                                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                                                    return someFun()
                                                                                                                                                } else 
                                                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                                                    return validateForm()
                                                                                                                                                }
    ">
</div>
```

**UPDATED:**

**Javascript**

```
 function someFun(){
    var urlInsert = '@Url.Action("myFunAction")';
        $.get(urlInsert, function () {
    });

}
```

Also tried below, but the controller func not calling

```
function myFunAction(){
    var formData = $("#Preference").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/advertiser/campaign/myFun',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('span.targetCount').text($.trim(data));
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
            var content = error.content;
            console.log(content.message);
            if (content.display_exceptions)
                console.log(content.exception.xdebug_message);
        },

    });
}
```

**Controller.php**  - Doesnt seem to be called

```
public function myFunAction(){
    echo '+++myFUN---';exit;

}
```

**Error:**

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tried dataType as html, json and text. Still same error.

Comment: I only see one JSON.parse in there.  You should try logging jqXHR and/or jqXHR.responseText before your code tries to parse it to see if your problem becomes clearer.

Comment: You mean console.log(jqXHR) before var error line ?

Comment: I just checked..it seems to be happening only in Firefox...in chrome i m getting the controller print statement

Answer (score 0):

My guess is either your post data or your response object is not considered valid json and that is why Firefox throws an error (maybe Chrome is more forgiving). What you could check is whether the request is send correctly and whether the response from the server actually arrives and whether it is valid json. You should consider returning valid json from your `myFunAction` method in your controller (instead of just printing a string like you do right now):

```
public function myFunAction(){
    $data = '+++myFUN---';

    return new JsonModel([
        'data' => $data
    ]);
}
```

Check more on how to properly return Json in Zend for example on this blog post here: https://akrabat.com/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/

Valid json response should have a `content-type` header set to `application/json` and have a valid json string in the response body. Zend `JsonModel` will help you with this.

When you post data you should also set the `content-type` of the request to `application-json`, like that the server understands that you are sending a json object with data.

I never use JQuery but I think it is done like this if I am not mistaken:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/advertiser/campaign/myFun',
  data: formData,
  contentType: "application/json",
});
```